# Get custom command line parameter during module install() process

Tags: module, dependency-injection, command-line

Is there a way to access command line parameters from inside the magento installer routines?  I'm attempting to set up a few custom variables representing our current environment (dev / test / prod) etc.  I was hoping to pass this in to the command line.

Like this...

```
public function install(
            \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
            \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context,
            \SOMETHING\INJECTED\FOR\COMMAND\LINE $cmdLine)
        {

            $setup->startSetup();
            // DO MY STUFF
            if ($cmdLine->getEnv() == "DEV") {
```

.... like that

I'm going back to search. Google is not cooperating right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a sample for this.

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-command